# The use of possesive pronouns with gerunds in the passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, gerunds, possessive-pronouns

Can I use possessive pronouns with gerunds in the passive voice?

In the active voice, a gerund modified by a possesive pronoun would sound like this, for example: "I didn't like his going to New York without me."

But would it be possible to use possesives together with gerunds in sentences like these: "I don't like his being talked about so negatively" or "His being talked about so negatively didn't make me happy"?

Comment: Yes, both those sentences are grammatical and easily understood.

Comment: Yes, but note that "going" and "being" are verbs not nouns.